When solving a balanced transportation problem, why is the allowable increase/decrease nonzero in sensitivity report for constraint RHS
I have the following 2 supplier 2 customer problem with total supply = total demand = 200.
$$\min x_{11} + 2 x_{12} + 2x_{21} + x_{22}$$
s.t. $x_{11}+x_{12}=80 \quad \tag{S1}$
$x_{21} + x_{22} = 120 \quad \tag{S2}$
$x_{11} + x_{21} = 100 \quad \tag{C1}$
$x_{12} + x_{22} = 100\quad \tag{C2}$
$$x\geq0$$
Excel provides a sensitivity report after solving this LP like:

As I understand, the general interpretation of "Allowable decrease" of 20 corresponding to the second constraint is that from its current value of 120, a decrease of 20 is allowed in the RHS of the second constraint and for each unit of decrease, the change in the optimal objective function value will be -2 (shadow price of 2 multiplied by -1 because of decrease).
But in this case, any change in the RHS of exactly any one constraint will immediately render the resulting LP infeasible. So, should not the allowable increase/decrease of all 4 constraints be 0?

Bug in Solver? I ran your example with CPLEX, and as expected it said the allowable change in either direction for any RHS value was zero.
